# Double space replaced automatically with single space when using TIDY HTML, and i dont want that to happen

Tags: html, tidy

I am using HTML TIDY and I see that if there is double space in my text/HTML to be fixed, Tidy would replace the double space with a single space, and I do not what that to happen, any help would be great???? here is my config for HTML Tidy.

```
tidy-mark: no
show-errors: 6
show-warnings: yes
output-xml: no
enclose-text: yes
wrap: 0
uppercase-tags: yes
uppercase-attributes: yes
show-body-only: yes
new-inline-tags: replaced,city,place,personname,country-region
```

Answer (score 1):

In most places in HTML, double spaces are treated as single spaces by the browser.  That is likely why HTML Tidy replaces them: they just take space in your HTML file for no benefit.  You need non-breaking spaces if you actually want two spaces to appear.

Comment: I was about to say the same thing, but multiple spaces *do* have their place when nesting HTML tags. I can see why one would want to keep them

Comment: @Pekka: It looks like HTML Tidy's "Layout Style" options do that formatting (tag indentation, etc.) for you.

Comment: that's true - didn't think of that. In that case, as long as it leaves them alone in `<pre>` tags, there indeed seems to be no reason to keep them.

Comment: @Pekka: According to the documentation, you need `indent: auto` in your config file to get indentation; otherwise, it will move everything to the left margin.

Comment: @everyone: Thanks for your replies guys, atleast now i know why its happning, but is there a way to stop it not from happning ??? because I want multiple spaces in there.

by the way i tried indent: auto, option it did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use option literal-attributes: yes (by default no) to not replace double space by single space inside attributes (where it should matters).

A typical case where you have something like :

```
<a href="/somewhere  .htm">click here</a>
```

And you need to keep the double space for the link to still works.